# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality application problem

Tags: inequality

Pennachi's "Asset Pricing" chapter 4 derives:

$$
\frac{E[R_{i}-R_{f}]}{\sigma_{R_{i}}}=-\rho_{m_{01},R_{i}}\frac{\sigma_{m_{01}}}{E[m_{01}]}
$$

Then, he states that the fact that $-1\leq \rho_{m_{01},R_{i}} \leq 1$ implies that:
$$
\left | \frac{E[R_{i}-R_{f}]}{\sigma_{R_{i}}} \right | \leq \frac{\sigma_{m_{01}}}{E[m_{01}]}
$$

This last step is not clear to me, could you please explain how it follows? Wikipedia says that it follows from Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, but I cannot figure out how.

P.S. $E[\cdot]$ is expected value, $\sigma$ is standard deviation, $\rho$ is correlation coefficient. $R_{i}$, $R_{f}$ and $m_{01}$ are all real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the absolute value of both sides. Then note that $\lvert \rho \rvert \le 1$, and you get your inequality. Beats me where they see Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I got this answer in another forum: "Basically in the first equation a=rb and we have |r|≤1 so certainly b>a as we have in the second equation. Taking absolutes just drops the signs." I think your answer has the same underlying idea, so thank you!